# calling constructor is failing in stl list

Tags: c++, class, stl

I created the following program

```
/* Directed Graph-- WEIGHTED    */

#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<list>
using namespace std;

class node{
    int vertex;
    int weight;

public:
    node(){
        vertex=0;
        weight=0;
    }

    node(int a, int b){
            vertex=a;
            weight=b;
       }
};

int main()
{
    int no_of_vertex, no_of_relation;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter no of Vertices:";
    cin>>no_of_vertex;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter no of relations:";
    cin>>no_of_relation;

    vector < list<node> > adj_list[no_of_vertex+1];
    int sv=0, ew=0, dv=0;
    for(int i=0; i<no_of_relation; i++)
    {
        cout<<endl<<"Enter Source_Vertex, Edge_Weight, Destination_Vertex:";
        cin>>sv;
        cin>>ew;
        cin>>dv;
        adj_list[sv].push_back(node (dv, ew));
    }

return 0;
}
```

I am getting an error

```
no matching function for call to 'std::vector<std::list<node> >::push_back(node)'
```

at

```
adj_list[sv].push_back(node (dv, ew));
```

I cannot understand the cause of error. Just a hint might do it all.
I am somewhat new to c++, help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
adj_list[sv].push_back(node (dv, ew));
```

could be valid if `adj_list` would be defined as

```
vector < node > adj_list[no_of_vertex+1];
```

But you defined it as

```
vector < list<node> > adj_list[no_of_vertex+1];
```

The compiler is unable to convert implicitly the object `node (dv, ew)` of type `node` to an object of type `std::list<node>`.

You could write for example

```
adj_list[sv].push_back({ 1, node (dv, ew) } );
```

but it seems that your code in any case makes no sense.

Comment: oh i got my mistake,
its true that very statement is creating error 
but the error is due to usage of wrong type of brackets while declaring a vector of list [ ] ....
right way would be :::
 vector < list<node> > adj_list(no_of_vertex+1);

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use:

```
adj_list[sv][sv].push_back(node (dv, ew));
```